# Typescript compiler emits unreadable code

Tags: typescript, tsc

I'm writing a chrome extension, and one of the requirements for review is that the code is readable. When I use async functions, the tsc emits insanely unreadable that looks like this:

```js
var __generator = (this && this.__generator) || function (thisArg, body) {
    var _ = { label: 0, sent: function() { if (t[0] & 1) throw t[1]; return t[1]; }, trys: [], ops: [] }, f, y, t, g;
    return g = { next: verb(0), "throw": verb(1), "return": verb(2) }, typeof Symbol === "function" && (g[Symbol.iterator] = function() { return this; }), g;
    function verb(n) { return function (v) { return step([n, v]); }; }
    function step(op) {
        if (f) throw new TypeError("Generator is already executing.");
        while (_) try {
            if (f = 1, y && (t = op[0] & 2 ? y["return"] : op[0] ? y["throw"] || ((t = y["return"]) && t.call(y), 0) : y.next) && !(t = t.call(y, op[1])).done) return t;
            if (y = 0, t) op = [op[0] & 2, t.value];
            switch (op[0]) {
                case 0: case 1: t = op; break;
                case 4: _.label++; return { value: op[1], done: false };
                case 5: _.label++; y = op[1]; op = [0]; continue;
                case 7: op = _.ops.pop(); _.trys.pop(); continue;
                default:
                    if (!(t = _.trys, t = t.length > 0 && t[t.length - 1]) && (op[0] === 6 || op[0] === 2)) { _ = 0; continue; }
                    if (op[0] === 3 && (!t || (op[1] > t[0] && op[1] < t[3]))) { _.label = op[1]; break; }
                    if (op[0] === 6 && _.label < t[1]) { _.label = t[1]; t = op; break; }
                    if (t && _.label < t[2]) { _.label = t[2]; _.ops.push(op); break; }
                    if (t[2]) _.ops.pop();
                    _.trys.pop(); continue;
            }
            op = body.call(thisArg, _);
        } catch (e) { op = [6, e]; y = 0; } finally { f = t = 0; }
        if (op[0] & 5) throw op[1]; return { value: op[0] ? op[1] : void 0, done: true };
    }
};
```

Because of that, my extension is getting rejected from the CWS. Is there a plugin to keep the emitted js readable?

Comment: are you sure you don't have something else in the build process causing minification/uglification? TS doesn't do this by default afaik. Look for webpack, gulp, babel, etc., settings. Or maybe you have an older targeted ECMA standard than I do.

Comment: This is what an async function looks like when it's transpiled to ES5. If the rest of your transpiled code is somewhat readable, I doubt this will cause any problems. People at Google should be 'pro' enough to regognize this code.  :)

Comment: As a side note, this is why I don't recommend people to use `async/await` in browser code, because it will bloat the bundle size and adds a (theoretical) performance hit. Good old `.then()` and `.catch()` is better for browsers.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since chrome extensions work only on chromium-based browsers you don't have to worry about converting to JavaScript that is supported by older browsers.

This means that you can bump up the `target` in your `tsconfig` file. Because less conversion is being done typescript should produce more readable code.

Add / Change this in your `tsconfig.json` file.

```json
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! Turns out I was targeting ES3 in the tsconfig.js. I'm targeting esnext now.